# Trouble with simple C# WPF custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I'm having some difficulty finding simple examples while using WPF when it comes to control bindings and I'm hoping you can help me get my head around it with this simple example.

Can you please explain why this doesn't work and also a simple way to get it running?

I've looked at numerous tutorials but they are all still a little advanced for me at this stage I think so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DemoProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:DemoProject"
    Title="DemoProject" >

    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{x:Static custom:MainWindow.CommandEnterKeyPressed}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static custom:MainWindow.CommandEnterKeyPressed}"
            Executed="CommandEnterKeyPressedExecuted" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>   
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace DemoProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { 
        private static RoutedUICommand CommandEnterKeyPressed;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static RoutedUICommand CommandEnterKeyPressed = new RoutedUICommand();

        private void CommandEnterKeyPressedExecuted(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter key was pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the errors

> "The member "CommandEnterKeyPressed" is not recognised or is not
>   accessible" and "No overload for "'ommandEnterKeyPressed' matches
>   delegate 'System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventHandler'".

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs` to `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`

```
private void CommandEnterKeyPressedExecuted(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
```

Should be

```
private void CommandEnterKeyPressedExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

`CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs` is used for `CanExecute` event. You should also remove this line

```
private static RoutedUICommand CommandEnterKeyPressed;
```

and leave only public declaration of your `RoutedUICommand`

Comment: Wow - can't believe I didn't spot that! Thanks! That's helped get me on the right track.
I've now got a problem with the <CommandBinding> tag in XML "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value" - do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: So `CommandBinding` has now `Command` and `Executed` event handler? Is the problem in design?

Comment: Thanks - yes, I had initialized the component before creating the RoutedUICommand. Works perfectly now, thank you for your help :D